# Jquery dynamically create link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of JQuery that creates a row in a table and in one of the cells there is an X that is surrounded by a class. When it is dynamically created and then clicked on the click listener does not fire.
Here is the code.

```
$('#add').click(function() {
   $( '#table' ).append('<td class="x">X</td></tr>');
});
$('.x').click(function() {
  alert('Fired');
});
```

Comment: You're not adding "TR" at the start of your new row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `<td>` element does not yet exist when you register your event handler, you have to use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for the handler to be triggered later:

```
$(".x").live("click", function() {
    alert("Fired");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".x").live("click", function()
{
   alert("Fired");
});
```

Live adds events to anything added later in the DOM as well as what's currently there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('.x').click(function() {
  alert('Fired');
});
```

Change to this

```
$('.x').live('click', function() {
  alert('Fired');
});
```

It binds the click function to any created element with class x

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the .live function for content that's dynamically generated.

so replace

```
$('.x').click(function() {
```

with

```
$('.x').live('click',function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are first creating the listener to all `.x` elements (of which there are presumably zero), then later adding new `.x` elements.

There are two solutions: one is to use jQuery `live`, the other is to rewrite your code:

```
var xClickHandler = function() {
    alert('Fired');
};
$('#add').click(function() {
    $('#table').append(
        $('<td class="x">X</td></tr>').click(xClickHandler);
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `live` instead of `click`:

```
$('.x').live("click", function() {
    alert('Fired');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The html you are appending to the table has a typo, you have missed out the beggining tr tag:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
   $( '#table' ).append('<tr><td class="x">X</td></tr>');
});
$('.x').click(function() {
  alert('Fired');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the live method. http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$('.x').live('click', function() {
  // Live handler called.
});
```